# scala StackOverflow on implicit object unapply

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit

I'm writing a typeclass to convert between types and I'm noticing something unusual with the unapply method on implicit objects. Concretely

```
object IntString extends PartialFunction[String, Int] {
  def isDefinedAt(x: String) = Try(x.toInt).isSuccess
  def apply(v1: String) = v1.toInt
  def unapply(a:String):Option[Int] = if(this.isDefinedAt(a)) Some(this.apply(a)) else None
}

val s = "1000"
val IntString(i) = s
```

works perfectly but

```
implicit object IntString extends PartialFunction[String, Int] {
  def isDefinedAt(x: String) = Try(x.toInt).isSuccess
  def apply(v1: String) = v1.toInt

  def unapply(a:String):Option[Int] = if(this.isDefinedAt(a)) Some(this.apply(a)) else None
}

val s = "1000"
val IntString(i) = s
```

gives a StackOverflow at the `apply` method. I'd like to be able to have the object be implicit so I can do something like

```
def parse[A,B](a:A)(implicit ev:PartialFunction[A,B]) = ev(a)
```

in addition to explicit apply/unapply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all goes wrong in `apply`, specifically with `v1.toInt`. `java.lang.String` does not have a `toInt` method. It is provided implicitly by `StringLike`. But `Int` *also* has a `toInt` method, and you provide an implicit conversion from `String => Int`.

The compiler sees that you want to call `toInt` on a `String`. Rather than choosing the enriched method from `StringLike`, the compiler knows that `Int` has a `toInt` method, and you're providing an implicit `String => Int` in scope, so it uses that. But using your conversion calls `apply` again, and it repeats the process infinitely.

A simple solution would be to use an actual type class, and not `PartialFunction`:

```
trait Conv[A, B] {
    def isDefinedAt(x: A): Boolean
    def apply(v1: A): B
    def unapply(a: A): Option[B]
}

implicit object IntString extends Conv[String, Int] {

  def isDefinedAt(x: String) = Try(x.toInt).isSuccess

  def apply(v1: String): Int = v1.toInt

  def unapply(a: String): Option[Int] =
    if(this.isDefinedAt(a)) Some(this.apply(a)) else None
}

scala> val IntString(i) = s
i: Int = 1000
```

And you'd change `parse` to:

```
def parse[A, B](a: A)(implicit ev: Conv[A,B]) = ev(a)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a very clear explanation of what is happening. I thought there was some kind of unexpected implicit trickiness going on but I wasn't sure what. I actually want to keep extending `PartialFunction` (my actual implementation has a typeclass that extends it) so that I can do things like `orElse` and `andThen` on it, but based on your answer I changed `v1.toInt` to `Integer.parseInt(v1)` and it worked.